# prove that group of order 275 has non trivial center.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be finite group of order $275 = 5^2\cdot11$.
 prove that $Z(G)=\{g\in G:\forall h\in G\space\space gh=hg\}\not=\{e\}$.

Using the Sylow theorems I manged to prove that $G$ has normal subgroup of order $11$. I also tried letting $G$ act on itself by conjugation, yet haven't manged to find anything useful.

Comment: Is $G$ a direct product of $p$-groups? In this case, we can take an element from one of the $p$-groups which is in the center of that $p$-group but is not the identity ($p$-groups have non-trivial center). That ought commute with everything in $G$. 
If $G$ is the semi-direct product of this subgroup of order $11$ and a $5$-sylow, then by the group operation of semidirect products, we can see that a non-trivial element of the center of the $5$-sylow should commute with everything in $G$.

Comment: @Myridium the $5$-Sylow group is commutative.

Comment: Do you mean that elements of the $5$-sylow commute with everything in $G$? Such a statement needs a proof.

Comment: @Myridium This is not what I meant. You said in your comment "the center of the $5$-Sylow". Since the $5$-Sylow is abelian it is equal to its center.

Comment: Okay, but if the $5$-sylow is abelian, this requires work to be shown.

Answer (score 2):

Denote the $11$ group by $N$. And its complament (of order $25$) by $H$.
Then $$G=N\rtimes H.$$
The automorphism group of $N$ is cyclic of order $10$.
Hence $H$ can act trivialy (and the group is commutative) or $H$ can act by an element of order $5$. Assume the action is non-trivial. If $H$ is cyclic with generator $h$, then $h^5$ acts trivialy and hence $h^5$ is in the center of $G$.
If $H=C_5\times C_5$ generated by $a,b$. Then either $a$ or $b$ acts trivialy or
there exist $i,j$ such that $a^ib^j$ acts trivialy.

Comment: This is a nice answer but I think you may be making it a little confusing by distinguishing between $\;H\;$ cyclic and non- cyclic. The point is that either the action is trivial and we have an abelian group, or else there is a non-unit element (and thus of order dividing $\;25\;$ but $\;\neq 1\;$) acting trivially on $\;N\;$ , and that's all. +1

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks for your comment. I know that, but I thought maybe OP (don't know what his background) will need mre details.

Answer (score 2):

A different solution,

If there is a uniqe sylow-$5$ group then we are one so let $P$ and $Q$ be two sylow $5$ subgroup. Notice that $P\cap Q$ can not be trivial, otherwise $PQ$ has $25^2$ elements which is not possible. Hence $|P\cap Q|=5$. As $P\cap Q$ is normal in both $P$ and $Q$ then it is normal $<P,Q>=G$. Since $P\cap Q$ is normal in $G$ it commutes with the elements of sylow-$11$ subgroups which concludes the result.

Comment: I don't understand why $P \cap Q$ is normal in G (I understand why it's normal in $P$ and $Q$). And why does this then imply that all elements of $P \cap Q$ commute with all the elements of the 11-sylow group?

Comment: @dorkichar Since $P$ and $Q$ generate $G$ and $U=P\cap Q$ is normal in both $P$ and $Q$, it is also normal in $G$. For second question, it is a well known fact that if you have two normal subgroups $M$ and $N$ such that $M\cap N=1$, then the elements of $M$ and $N$ commutes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, @mesel! Most of this makes sense, but I still don't understand how P and Q generate G when they don't have any elements of the 11-sylow group, and so elements of order 11.

Comment: Set $H=\langle P,Q\rangle$. Then clearly, $25=|P|<|H|\leq 275=|G|$. Moreover, $|H|$ divides 275 by Lagrange theorem, which forces that $|H|=275$, and so $H=G$.

Comment: Thank you, @mesel!